# <c:forEach> tag is giving the list values multiple times repeatedly in my jsp

Tags: jsp, loops

below is my code in jsp

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${historyList}" varStatus="iter">
<tr>
<td>${list[0]}</td>
<td>${list[1]}</td>
<td>${list[2]}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is the above code is giving the list of items correctly.But each value is repeated 6 times.

Output:

```
 0.456 1234 OK
 0.456 1234 OK
 0.456 1234 OK
 0.456 1234 OK
 0.456 1234 OK
 0.456 1234 OK
 1.209 3457 YES
 // this above row is also 6 times repeating
```

I am getting all the values but repeatedly getting like above.Please solve my problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It already is iterating the list, so it is not necessary to access all the items of the array by the specific position `${list[0]}${list[1]}`, just access the current one of the iteration like the example below:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${historyList}" varStatus="iter">
<tr>
<td>${item}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**Update**

Your code looks fine as the items of historyList are of array type. I think the issue is that the historyList has duplicated items.

Comment: I need the values seperately.Column wise.i.e., in first column 0.456,2nd column 1234,3rd column OK like that..

Comment: @user2515189 did you check if the values in the historyList aren't repeated? i checked your code again and it seems that the items of the historyList are array, right?

Comment: yes.So I am accessing them using indexes.If I simply call ${item} is giving some hashcode symbols.So I am calling ${item[0]}...

Comment: @user2515189 you are right to call the `${item[0]}`, I didn't realize it was an array when posted it... anyway I think the issue is that the historyList has the duplicated items, because your original code looks fine.